# Avoid mutating props in nested forms

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a form divided in two sections each communicated with parent form via props. How do I avoid mutating props passed from parent form?

---

ParentForm.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <AddressForm :form-data="formData.address" />
    <OtherForm :form-data="formData.other" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        address: {
          address_no: "",
          country: "",
        },
        other: {
          remarks: "",
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

AddressForm.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="formData.address_no" />
    <input v-model="formData.country" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AddressForm",
  props: { formData: { type: Object, required: true } },
};
</script>
```

OtherForm.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="formData.remarks" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "OtherForm",
  props: { formData: { type: Object, required: true } },
};
</script>
```

---

Changing value of input fields in `AddressForm.vue` or `OtherForm.vue` will trigger a warning on props mutation. I wanted to know how do I communicate up/down with the forms without mutating a props?

I have come up with possible solutions but I don't know which one should I go for (and also how to implement it)

- Clone `formData` prop in `created()` and link `v-model` to the local cloned `formData` instead of prop. Then watch the cloned `formData` and emit every time the value changed.
- Bind using [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) instead of props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your child forms as [custom inputs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) using `v-model` instead of passing props:

AddressForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input :value="value.address_no" @input="$emit('input',{...value,address_no:$event.target.value)" />
    <input :value="value.country" @input="$emit('input',{...value,country:$event.target.value)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AddressForm",
  props: { value: { type: Object, required: true } },
};
</script>
```

OtherForm :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea :value="value.remarks" @input="$emit('input',{...value,remarks:$event.target.value)"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "OtherForm",
  props: { value: { type: Object, required: true } },
};
</script>
```

in parent component :

```
    <AddressForm v-model="formData.address" />
    <OtherForm v-model="formData.other" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another question - emitting on every @input is not very ideal for me (I'm working on a very large form). Is there anyway to optimize this?

Comment: it's my pleasure, add `lazy` modifier to `v-model` directive like `<OtherForm v-model.lazy="formData.other" />`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign in `beforeMount()` those props to some data values and then $emit them back.
Obviously, `v-model` should refer to the properties defined in `data()`.

Comment: Thanks, Can you provide an example?